# Increasing distance between the reversible reaction arrows

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I am making a large poster, and when I use `\chemfig{}` to make arrows, `\arrow{}` the reversible reaction arrow is having very small distance between the two lines. Can anyone suggest how to manually increase the distance between the reversible reaction arrow ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
        \chemfig{2H_2O} \arrow{<=>} \chemfig{4H} \+ \chemfig{O_2} 
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

Here the `<=>` creates reversible reaction arrow, but the spacing between the two lines is very small for a huge poster. How to increase this space?

Comment: What you provided is not a MWE. You should give us a full, compilable code with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, with all relevant code parts.

Comment: The distance seems to be hard-coded inside `chemfig.tex` (look for `\definearrow3{<=>}{%` -- the `yshift=1pt` and `yshift=-1pt` clauses define the offset between the two arrows). So, you would need to create a hacked version of that command to change the vertical distance.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MichaelPalmer wrote in the comment, you have to create a new type of arrow, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\definearrow{4}{<S>}{%
    \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
    \path[allow upside down](\CF@arrow@start@node)--(\CF@arrow@end@node)%
    node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=#4](\CF@arrow@start@node @u0){}%
    node[pos=0,sloped,yshift=-#4](\CF@arrow@start@node @d0){}%
    node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=#4](\CF@arrow@start@node @u1){}%
    node[pos=1,sloped,yshift=-#4](\CF@arrow@start@node @d1){};%
    \begingroup
    \pgfarrowharpoontrue
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node @u0)--(\CF@arrow@start@node @u1);%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style](\CF@arrow@start@node @d1)--(\CF@arrow@start@node @d0);%
    \endgroup
    \CF@arrow@display@label{#1}{0.5}+\CF@arrow@start@node{#2}{0.5}-\CF@arrow@end@node%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \schemestart[0,1,line width=1mm]
        \chemfig{2H_2O} \arrow{<S>[][][][4pt]} \chemfig{4H} \+ \chemfig{O_2} 
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

where I set the distance to 4pt and the thickness of the lines to 1mm.

Another approach, if you want to tweak the arrows even more, then look here:

[How to change distance within a reversible edge and increase the font size in chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390057/how-to-change-distance-within-a-reversible-edge-and-increase-the-font-size-in-ch/397270#397270)

[How do we mirror a reversible reaction arrow in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156472/how-do-we-mirror-a-reversible-reaction-arrow-in-chemfig/156542#156542)

[How to get different colors for reversible arrows in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405641/how-to-get-different-colors-for-reversible-arrows-in-chemfig)

Answer (score 3):

Use the key `double arrow sep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
% Default arrow double sep = 2pt
\schemestart
    \chemfig{2H_2O} \arrow{<=>} \chemfig{4H} \+ \chemfig{O_2}
\schemestop

\bigskip

% Increase arrow spacing
\setchemfig{arrow double sep=6pt}
\schemestart
    \chemfig{2H_2O} \arrow{<=>} \chemfig{4H} \+ \chemfig{O_2}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not really sufficient: with a huge font the thickness doesn't vary and the arrows get longer.

Comment: @egreg That can be tweaked with the other chemfig options. If the OP gives more information about how this is being used I can advise further. Otherwise, imho the central question has been answered.